# Auto creating a task-manager

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a task manager using macros, but I have no idea how i can do it with the sheets i am using atm.

I made a sheet which shows
- Who wil execute the task
- What is the urgence of the task
- Where should it be done
- On what construction-element the task should be done
- What is the task that should be done
- A empty-line to place notes.

In excel my sheet wil look like:

The A1 line wil be headers.

```
    A                       B           C                D               E          F
A1  Executer                Urgence  Location      Construction-Element Quantity   Activity

A2  Housemaster             1       Livingroom     Door                2meter      Replace
A3  Technical Deperartment  4       Kitchen        Ceiling             0,5meter    Fix
A4  External company        2       Bathroom       Floor               1 meter     Repair
```

I would like excel to auto-create new tabs for every executer. So each executer get a tab with all task he or she should do.

Excuse me for my poor english, its not my native language.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the sheet for each executer and give them the executers name. Then go thru each of that new sheets and delete all rows where the executer name is different from the sheet name. This can all be done via VBA so that you have a fully automated solution on the end.

But that's not been done in one or two rows so you can not expect that we provide the complete code for that ;-). Let us know when you have a specific problem on one of the steps.